# I have trouble finding my Windows drive on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: boot, hard-drive

I'm totally new to Ubuntu 18.04 Ubuntu. oh it's fun so far.
I booted Ubuntu using external SSD (NOT dual boot), and tried to find my Windows 10. but failed.
My laptop is Dell XPS 13 9350. 
Could you help me find my drive? I spent a lot of time on this, But was not able to find proper solutions.

Output of `lsblk`:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: The `lsblk` command will show you the atached devices. Your Windows drive will probably be there. To access the files the Windows file system will need to be *mounted*. Use `df` to see whether or not it is already mounted.

Answer (score 0):

Use the command
    "`sudo update-grub`"
Type your password(though it will be invisible).
You should be able to find windows OS.

Restart the system.

Comment: Thanks for replies.
I did "sudo update-grub" , reboot and typed "lablk". but my internal SSD doesn's still show up.
My SSD is 512GB, Internal.
Just in case, would it be related to BIOS option?

Comment: I think your system is booting from that external SSD, better go through bios settings and change the boot priority to your internal disk.
Start the computer and press ESC, F1, F2, F8 or F10 during the initial startup screen. Depending on the BIOS manufacturer, a menu may appear.